# Cells not aligned with header - JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid (not Gurrido version / jqGrid 4.6 version) and i got an issue with the alignement of the cells and headers.

[You can see the problem here :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7fgl.png)

And the code of the grid :

```js
            gridTr.jqGrid({
                url: "http://localhost/projetMecenat/public/tranches/projet/{{ $ID_PROJET }}",
                mtype: "POST",
                datatype: 'json',
                colNames: ["Type contact","Numéro","Libellé","Montant mini","Montant maxi","Montant réel"],
                colModel: [
                    {name: "TYPE_CONTACT", sortable: false, width: 100, align:"center"},
                    {name: "CPT_TRANCHE", width: 30, align:"center"},
                    {name: "LIBCOD", width: 150, align: "center", sortable: false},
                    {name: "MT_SOUTIEN_MINI", sortable: false, width: 100, align:"center"},
                    {name: "MT_SOUTIEN_MAXI", width: 100, align:"center"},
                    {name: "MT_REEL", width: 200, align: "center", sortable: false}
                ],
                loadtext: "Chargement...",
                viewrecords: true,
                emptyrecords: "Aucune délibération",
                width: 680,
                height: 300,
                rowNum: 100,
                sortable: true,
                loadonce: true,
                hidegrid: false,
                multipleSearch: true,
                shrinkToFit: false,
                gridview: true,
                autoencode: false,
                gridComplete: function() { 
                    console.log("grid tranche load successfully");
                }
            })
```

The JSON send from the server :

```
[{"ID_CONTREPARTIE":1,"FAMIL_CTRPRT_":1,"LIBEL_CTRPRT":"Contrepartie 1","DETAIL_CTRPRT":null,"PRECISION_TRCH":null,"CORRESP_MONETAIRE":null,"NUM_MINI":2000,"NUM_MAXI":2500,"DTNEW":"2020-02-17","DTMAJ":"2020-02-17","UTILNEW":"HMA","UTILMAJ":"SBR","ID_PROJET":201,"CDCOD":"FAMIL_CTRPRT","CLECOD":1,"LIBCOD":"Communication","VALCOD1":"","VALCOD2":null,"FAMIL_CTRP":"Communication"}]
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Can you please post your response from the server, which causes this problem and is the important part of the issue.

Comment: hi sorry i don't have any error message or response from the server.. i have solved the issue by just delete the witdth attribute of each column... but i got the problem on a other grid where it's necessary to specified a width for each column

Comment: No matter if you have error or not from the response. The response is needed in order to see the full picture of the problem.  In most cases such error is caused if the response is not in pair name value format - i.e if oprion in jsonReader repeatitems is true  and you response is similar like those: `"rows" : [
    {"id" :"1", "cell" :["Bob", "232-532-6268"]},`, so in order to solve the problem we need the response.

Comment: hi, sorry for the long response i was busy on some other stuffs, i have edited my post with the response from the server